# FirebaseApp по умолчанию не инициализируется в процессе

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-android

Подключил Firebase Analytics в свой проект. Добавил пару зависимостей, но выдаёт в Log такую ошибку:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.axdiscussion. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот Build Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {

```
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.axdiscussion"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.+'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.3.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'

testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

}

В MainActivity добавил инициализацию методом `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


private static final int SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);

    if(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser() == null){
        startActivityForResult(
                AuthUI.getInstance()
                .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                .build(),
                SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE

        );
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Welcome " + FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                        .getCurrentUser()
                        .getDisplayName(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();

        displayChatMessages();
    }
}


private void displayChatMessages() {
}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == SIGN_IN_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "Successfully signed in. Welcome!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            displayChatMessages();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this,
                    "We couldn't sign you in. Please try again later.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();

            // Close the app
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Какая версия плагина `com.google.gms:google-services` подключена?

Comment: @Eugene Krivenja, версия : 4.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Сам решил свою проблему. Кому интересно, то дело состоит в том, что нужно синхронизировать в Build Gradle `com.google.gms:google-services` до последней версии, а на самом эмуляторе обновить Google Play Services. При этом, нужно в методе `onCreate()` добавить вызов `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);`

Comment: В 4.1.0 просто багов много, раньше откатывались на 4.0.1, теперь нужно на 4.2.0 переходить.

Comment: @Eugene Krivenja, спасибо за пояснение.